# how to stop reloading parent window while child window gets open

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts2, popupwindow

> I have a form submit, where it get the values from the form and goes
>   to next page... here I have a hyperlink to open a child window, while
>   I click, it opens the child window and simultaneously it reloads the
>   parent window. I have a action configured to the parent window which
>   has a Database insert statement too.
>
> The problem is that while I click the link it call my action
>   again(because of page reload), in this action I wrote if condition to
>   check null/empty string from the previous page form submit. since this
>   is the second time the action loads it looks of the fields(but
>   actually those fields are in my previous page form). so it take null
>   while checking my if condition.
>
> Another problem is that when I solve the above problem here comes the
>   SQL insert statement, which is about to execute 2nd time. I dont want
>   this to happen or I dont want my action to execute while I open the
>   popup window and I want to populate the selected value from the popup
>   to the parent window.

**code used for opening the popup**

```
 function select_reactant()
    {
        window.open ("SeriesTab.action?component=reactant",
            "mywindow","scrollbars=1,resizable=1,width=1000,height=1000");  
        };
```

**This is the place where I open the popup and want to populate the value selected from the popup to the textfiled here**

```
<tr>
    <td><a href="" onclick="select_reactant();">reactant</a></td>
    <td><s:textfield name="reactant" id="reactantId" readonly="true" theme="simple"/></td>
  </tr>
```

**jquery to get back the value form popup to parent window**

```
$(window.opener.document).find('#reactantId').val(rxn);
```

**the code inside action below is what the action that I mention at the beginning**

```
if(Rxn!=null||!Rxn.equals(""))  //Rxn is the field variable for previous page
{ 
//my insert statement
}
```

while I run I get nullpointer error since the value for Rxn is reset to null by the page reload due to popup opening done by

```
window.open
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this

***HTML***

```
<a href="#" id="anchSelectReactant">reactant</a>
```

***jQuery***

```
$(function(){
    $("#anchSelectReactant").click(function(){
        select_reactant();
        return false;
    });
});
```